# Civirule - Action : force override status

Tags: civirules

Is it possible to override permanently a status from 'pending' to 'new' with a civirule ?

CiviCRM doesn't do it automatically (issue I can't fix until now) and it would avoid me to do it manually every time a new member paid with credit card :-(

I can identify the right status :

> Contact has Membership of Status and Type : Membership type Est l'un de Adhésion annuelle & Membership status Est l'un de Pending

but I don't find out how to override the status

have a great day

Guillaume

Comment: So you are wanting the "Status Override" to be set as well?

Comment: Guillaume, I think you need to provide a bit more information about your workflow and what membership statuses you have set up. Surely you don't want to permanently override the status as "new".

Comment: I think there is something I haven't understood with this parameter :-( because "new" is supposed to not last for ever. I have to check this better. thanks for alerting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you should be able to do that with CiviRules but I am not sure if the action already exists? If not, you can create your own actions, documentation: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-action/

Comment: thanks Erik! At least I know it doesn't come out-of-the-box